# More Memcheck context lines

Tags: valgrind, memcheck

At the end of the program run, "leak check full" "show leak kinds all" shows a number of leak *incidents* in the form of sections like this, just as an example:

```
[...]
==12522== 
==12522== x bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record y of z
==12522==    at 0x4C2BBAF: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==12522==    by 0x42350D: whatever_1 (whatever_1.c:3401)
==12522==    by 0x4225B9: whatever_2 (whatever_2.c:2948)
==12522==    by 0x41D93E: whatever_3 (whatever_3.c:1185)
==12522==    by 0x423A07: whatever_4 (whatever_4.c:1370)
==12522==    by 0x4294A4: whatever_5 (whatever_5.y:1413)
==12522==    by 0x403998: whatever_6 (whatever_6.c:205)
==12522==    by 0x4038AC: whatever_7 (whatever_7.c:180)
==12522==    by 0x4036AF: whatever_8 (whatever_8.c:143)
==12522==    by 0x413C7F: whatever_test_0 (whatever_9.c:53)
==12522==    by 0x413F92: whatever_tests (whatever_10.c:177)
==12522==    by 0x45AD69: run_tests (whatever_11.c:153)
==12522==
[...]
```

The topmost scope is `main`, and in multiple blocks, like this one, there is enough depth that the call stack doesn't show up to `main`. In other *incidents*, there's enough context to show every level.

I've seen that, in this host, only 12 levels are shown here (`vg_replace_malloc.c` then my 11 user levels).

**Can this be configured to show more than 12 levels?**

I've read Valgrind arguments, Memcheck arguments, have increased verbosity, with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the option --num-callers (that has default value 12):

```
--num-callers=<number>    show <number> callers in stack traces [12]
```